# Select object in GIMP

Tags: gimp, selection

Is there cursor selection tool for GIMP?

I mean simple mouse selector that e.g. move objects within page - with mouse cursor.

There many custom selection tools , but i'ven't found the simplest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is <kbd>Move Tool</kbd> which you can use for moving objects. Shortcut key: <kbd>M</kbd>.

Comment: Also, holding down the space bar changes the active tool to Move temporarily. The Move tool remains active as long as the space bar is held down.

Comment: DaveParillo: That's incorrect, holding space bar down scrolls the entire canvas, which is different from the move tool, which moves individual items/layers.